# How can i divide images into squares for clicking objects?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I have a biology project. I need to make a game. There will be questions asking parts of brain and user will click on image how can detect it ? I tried image mapping but its calibration is so bad.

[image: brain image]

Comment: Please post relevant code so we can see what you're working on and show us what you've already tried.

Comment: You could make a SVG image of it and than using JS code to add a click event.

Comment: What does "calibration is so bad" mean?

Comment: Did you try an online tool like http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/ ?

Comment: I recommend SVG. Lots of other things you can do with SVG that you cant do with an image. +1 H.Pauwelyn

Comment: @Icewine — I think you mean a raster not an image there.

Comment: @Quentin No, sorry I meant image map

Comment: @LuudJacobs https://jsfiddle.net/ozaksen/f9z9adz5/ here is the code

Comment: @JJJ when I used an online image mapper but when I copied that into my local HTML code it was not correct

Comment: Well either the online image mapper's is bad or you made a mistake. Image maps aren't inherently inaccurate. They work just fine if you map them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my optionion, the best way to do what you want is by using a SVG image. Just add the SVG code inline with your HTML code, add some CSS and add an event listener to the element. See example below:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('kiwi')[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("You've clicked on the kiwi.");
});
```

```css
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 164px;
}

.kiwi {
  fill: #94d31b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.kiwi:hover {
  fill: #ace63c;
}

.ground {
  fill: #787f6a;
}

.ground:hover {
  filter: url(#pictureFilter);
  fill: #896d3d;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the kiwi.</p>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174" xml:space="preserve" class="logo">
  <ellipse class="ground" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
  <path class="kiwi" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03 c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341 c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933 c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991 c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875 c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489 c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309 c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876 c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413 c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566 c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156 c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351 c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247 c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331 z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111 C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z"/>
  <filter id="pictureFilter" >
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

For more information see [CSS-tricks: Using "inline" SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-7)